# Object fit class is working fine on desktop but on mobile screen it is not taking full width in tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3, tailwind-css

On hover i'm showing an image and content on it. On desktop the image takes the full width of parent. But on mobile screens it doesn't works. Is there a way to fix it ?

```
                    <div class="content mt-7">
                        <h2 class="title text-xl font-semibold">Fitness & Wellness</h2>
                        <p class="text-slate-400 mt-3">Custom software for fitness and wellness which is much needed professionally and personally.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="hidden group-hover:block ">
                        <div class="absolute inset-0 ">
                            <img src="./assets/images/services/Fitness 1.jpg" alt="" class="object-cover " >
                            <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-b from-transparent to-black"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="absolute bottom-0 right-0 left-0 mb-6">
                            <a href="" class="text-white text-xl font-bold">Fitness & Wellness</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: can you share a tailwind playground with a radom image ?

Comment: inspect the elements and check if there isn't any plain css rules toggling on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Here is one code you can try.

```
<div class="group">
<div class="content mt-7">
<h2 class="title text-xl font-semibold">Fitness & Wellness</h2>
 <p class="text-slate-400 mt-3">Custom software for fitness and wellness which 
  is much needed professionally and personally.
 </p>
 </div>
 <div class="invisible group-hover::visible">
  <div class="absolute inset-0 ">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1671726805766-de50e4327182?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="object-cover w-full h-full" >
  <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-b from-transparent to-black"> 
 </div>
 </div>

  <div class="absolute bottom-0 right-0 left-0 mb-6">
  <a href="" class="text-white text-xl font-bold">Fitness & Wellness</a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```